# How to check if an attribute match a specific regex at compile time?

Tags: c#, attributes, custom-attributes

I'm trying to understand how the [`AssemblyVersionAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.reflection.assemblyversionattribute%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) validates the string format at compile time. I would like to implement something similar in my application (if possible).

For example this is fine :

```
    [assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.0.1")]
```

But this one will cause a compiler error (because the format is invalid) :

```
    [assembly: AssemblyVersion("1a.0.0.1")]
```

How can I validate a custom attribute in the same way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIRC It's the compiler which has this functionality built-in and treats the `AssemblyVersion` attribute as special as it has to use its value and bake it into the resulting assembly. Unless writing your own compiler I doubt you could do this with custom attributes. IIRC the best you could do is to restrict the custom attribute target: whether it applies to classes, methods, properties, ... only.

Answer (score -1):

If you decided to implement by `Regular Expression` try this regex:

```
\[assembly: AssemblyVersion\(\"([0-9]{1,}(\.){1}){3}([0-9]{1,}){1}\"\)\]
```

Comment: completely misses the point. Do you know what an attribute _is_? In .NET/CLR?

Comment: @sehe the guy asked one way to validate the string `[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1a.0.0.1")]` by regex. Why the negative?

Comment: No. The guy asks how the [ATTRIBUTES](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_metadata#Attributes) do validation of the property string passed to their [constructor](http://en.csharp-online.net/ECMA-334%3A_8.7.8_Instance_constructors). It turns out, they don't (the named attribute [is special (see under _remarks_)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assemblyversionattribute(v=vs.71).aspx). Also I _did_ motivate the downvote to begin with, why don't you start by assuming you may have in fact missed the point?